# how to load own pkcs#11 shared library in thunderbird

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird, pkcs#11

Created shared library by defining some functionalities (using pkcs#11 library) like cryptographic operations.
.so file created successfully, but unable to load that module.

loading the library in Mozilla thunderbird:

Display the thunderbird Menu -> preferences -> Account Settings -> Security -> Security Devices(under 'certificates')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loading the pkcs# library:
Display the thunderbird Menu -> options ->advanced ->select "security devices" so that device manager is displayed.
now load your pkcs library by clicking on load and give required name and location of library file.
restart thurderbird to show your certificates in certificate manager.
thank you.